# customizable_multiselect_field is slow and lagging with big lists

Tags: flutter, dart, multi-select, flutter-packages

am trying to use customizable_multiselect_field 1.0.1 package in my sign up screen, and provide a list of options the user can choose from, and this is my code for the multiselectfield

```
 CustomizableMultiselectField(
                              customizableMultiselectWidgetOptions:
                                  CustomizableMultiselectWidgetOptions(
                                hintText: const Text('Please Select a value',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                                chipShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  side: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.red, width: 1),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              customizableMultiselectDialogOptions:
                                  const CustomizableMultiselectDialogOptions(),
                              dataSourceList: [
                                DataSource<String>(
                                  dataList: PropertyListAndPhase().propertyList,
                                  valueList: selectedPropertyList,
                                  options: DataSourceOptions(
                                      valueKey: 'key',
                                      labelKey: 'key',
                                      title: const Text(
                                        'Units',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                      )),
                                ),
                              ],
                              onChanged: ((value) => print(value)),
                              onSaved: (newValueList) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedPropertyList =
                                      newValueList!.cast<String>();
                                });
                              },
                              validator: ((value) {
                                if (value!
                                    .every((element) => element.isEmpty)) {
                                  return 'Please Select a value!';
                                }
                                return null;
                              }),
                            ),
```

and this is the list am providing

```
class PropertyListAndPhase {
  List<Map<String, String>> propertyList = [
    {'key':'E1'},
    {'key':'E1`'},
    
    and another 616 more items in the list am not going to add them for you not to hate me :D

];
}
```

and the code works fine, the problem is it's so slow and lags when i tap on it to choose,
it takes time to open and kind of lagging when i scroll in the list.

i tried to make the list shorter to know whether the number of items is the problem or not, and when the list got shorter it worked very smooth, the problem is that i need to add all the items on the list. what can i do to make it work without being slow or lagging?